# Write in a gpg script a passphrase located in an other textfile

Tags: linux, bash, gnupg, passphrase

I'm working on a script GPG and I would like to write a passphrase in the command encrypt. The passphrase is written on a textfile (`passphrase.txt`) in the same directory. So my goal is to be capable to write in the `script.sh` in place of `mypassphrase` the content of the text file `passphrase.txt`. I've already looked at the commands grep, sed an awk but encountered some difficulties to use them. Any suggestion ?

the command encrypt :

```
gpg --passphrase mypassphrase --local-user $1 --recipient $2 --armor --sign --output $3.asc --encrypt $3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
gpg --passphrase $(tr -d $'\n' < passphrase.txt) --local-user "$1" --recipient "$2" --armor --sign --output "$3.asc" --encrypt "$3"
```

Explanation:

bash knows [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$()`, which will return the output of a command:

```
output=$(command)
```

The command `tr -d $'\n' passphrase.txt` will output the contents of mypassphrase.txt but will remove additional new lines (if there are any).

If you can make sure that there are no additional new lines in the password file, you can use the following, faster command:

```
gpg --passphrase $(< mypassphrase.txt) --local-user "$1" --recipient "$2" --armor --sign --output "$3.asc" --encrypt "$3"
```